# How to use a keypress event in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I want to catch the enter key press event on the textbox below. To make it more clear I am using a `ng-repeat` to populate the tbody. Here is the HTML:

```
<td><input type="number" id="closeqty{{$index}}" class="pagination-right closefield" 
    data-ng-model="closeqtymodel" data-ng-change="change($index)" required placeholder="{{item.closeMeasure}}" /></td>
```

This is my module:

```
angular.module('components', ['ngResource']);
```

I am using a resource to populate the table and my controller code is:

```
function Ajaxy($scope, $resource) {
//controller which has resource to populate the table 
}
```

Comment: Is the input inside a form?

Comment: no .. its in a table!!

Comment: https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap helped. in case looking for a library.

Answer (score 817, accepted):

You need to add a `directive`, like this:

**Javascript**:

```
app.directive('myEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.myEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" my-enter="doSomething()">    
</div>
```

Comment: @DerekAdair The directive binds to the `keydown` and `keypress` events of the element it is attributed to. When the event is received the supplied expression is evaluated inside an `$apply` block.

Comment: More safe to defined the key like this : ```var key = typeof event.which === "undefined" ? event.keyCode : event.which;``` as long as event.which is not used by every browser. See comments here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4471635/2547632

Comment: I would add also `keyup` in the bind test

Comment: Separating out the actually triggered event handling function into the $scope of the directive allows for easier unit testing, because the fn() can be called directly in the test, instead of having to create and dispatch an actual event. Similar to [the other answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18625831/122764).

Comment: also note that using ng prefix is not recommended, as this can clash with future ng-* directives. Use your own instead

Comment: Why is he binding `keydown` and `keypress`. Isn't just enough with `keypress`?

Comment: Does anyone have the tests (jasmine) of that directive :)

Comment: Dont forget to destroy your bindings:
**scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
      element.unbind('keydown');
})**

Comment: @user1713964 Just use  `keydown` or `keyup` if you need `escape` key

Comment: Note, having both keydown and keypress can cause the action to be called twice. Bad news if you're making a server call, submitting a form, etc.

Comment: `$eval and $parse`  evaluate only angular expression. $eval uses $parse internally So $parse can be used instead $eval.  scope.$apply is trigger digest loop unnecessarily. Everything is handled by $parse internally.

Comment: updated directive is here https://gist.github.com/singhmohancs/317854a859098bffe9477f59eac8d915

Comment: `KeyboardEvent.wich` is now deprecated. You should use `KeyboardEvent.key` instead. Cf [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent).

Comment: Why are you not using ng-keypress, ng-keydown, ng-keyup? The code is cleaner if you do this because then you get the keyCode directly without any binding. You can handle all your keycodes in this one function instead of creating a directive for each key. Or you could create specific key directives (onEnter) but just supply a handler function that your main ng-keydown handler calls.

Comment: how would i use it in a nested directive? i.e. I've got a directive with it's own controller and template - when I use it in template it doesn't work. but if I used it outside of the directive, it will work just fine. is there a way to do it within the directive?

Comment: It took me a while of debugging to work out that the attribute is "my-enter" with a dash but the directive name is "myEnter" without a dash!

Comment: @ahnbizcad 13 is the keyCode for the enter key. You can find out which key corresponds to which code by looking up the according tables or by using http://keycode.info

Comment: When I change the name of the directive, for example, myEnter to mdEnter it doesn't work, how can I customize name?

Answer (score 361):

An alternative is to use standard directive `ng-keypress="myFunct($event)"`

Then in your controller you can have:

```
...

$scope.myFunct = function(keyEvent) {
  if (keyEvent.which === 13)
    alert('I am an alert');
}

...
```

Comment: To save other people some time, `ng-keypress` doesn't seem to be part of angular 1.0.x, `ui-keypress` (with slightly different calling semantics) is available though: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

Comment: I think the comment above this was aimed at a different answer. (Just for reference.)

Comment: Martin that's actually the function of a controller:  to handle UI events.

Comment: Better yet, use ngKeypress and pass the $event to a custom filter.

Comment: Best answer +1. Why should I make my own directive, if there is one, already included in Angular?

Comment: I was using this with codemirror and it couldn't catch the enter key, probably because it was binded with something else on default. The answer by EpokK works best

Comment: way better then creating a whole directive.

Comment: Kudos for simplicity.

Comment: I feel like this is a lot more palatable than creating custom directives, and even if you needed to do this multiple places, it would be simple enough to wrap the conditional logic in a function.  `if (isEnterKey($event)) { do stuff... )`

Answer (score 187):

My simplest approach using just angular build-in directive:

`ng-keypress`, `ng-keydown` or `ng-keyup`.

Usually, we want add keyboard support for something that already handled by ng-click.

for instance:

```
<a ng-click="action()">action</a>
```

Now, let's add keyboard support.

trigger by enter key:

```
<a ng-click="action()" 
   ng-keydown="$event.keyCode === 13 && action()">action</a>
```

by space key:

```
<a ng-click="action()" 
   ng-keydown="$event.keyCode === 32 && action()">action</a>
```

by space or enter key:

```
<a ng-click="action()" 
   ng-keydown="($event.keyCode === 13 || $event.keyCode === 32) && action()">action</a>
```

if you are in modern browser

```
<a ng-click="action()" 
   ng-keydown="[13, 32].includes($event.keyCode) && action()">action</a>
```

More about keyCode:
keyCode is deprecated but well supported API, you could use $evevt.key in supported browser instead.
See more in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Comment: the secret is the conditional before the method to be executed $event.which === 13 && action() - thanks!

Comment: '$event.which' is not working for me, but I found '$event.keyCode' which is working.

Comment: event.which is undefined in IE<9 on keydown and keyup.

Comment: "old browsers like IE9" .. never thought this day will come :)

Comment: Why hasn't anyone updated the code snippets here to use $event.keyCode then? I'd edit it myself, but I'm unable to for some reason.

Answer (score 104):

Another simple alternative:

```
<input ng-model="edItem" type="text" 
    ng-keypress="($event.which === 13)?foo(edItem):0"/>
```

And the ng-ui alternative:

```
<input ng-model="edItem" type="text" ui-keypress="{'enter':'foo(edItem)'}"/>
```

Comment: ng-ui it's ambiguous, instead you should say "UI.Utils" or share the link: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

Comment: ui-utils seems to be deprecated

Answer (score 19):

Here is what I figured out when I was building an app with a similar requirement,
it doesn't require writing a directive and it's relatively simple to tell what it does:

```
<input type="text" ng-keypress="($event.charCode==13)?myFunction():return" placeholder="Will Submit on Enter">
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use [ng-keydown](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeydown)
="myFunction($event)" as attribute.

```
<input ng-keydown="myFunction($event)" type="number">

myFunction(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {   // '13' is the key code for enter
        // do what you want to do when 'enter' is pressed :)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**html**

```
<textarea id="messageTxt" 
    rows="5" 
    placeholder="Escriba su mensaje" 
    ng-keypress="keyPressed($event)" 
    ng-model="smsData.mensaje">
</textarea>
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.keyPressed = function (keyEvent) {
    if (keyEvent.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('presiono enter');
        console.log('presiono enter');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also apply it to a controller on a parent element. This example can be used to highlight a row in a table by pressing up/down arrow keys.

```
app.controller('tableCtrl', [ '$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element) {
  $scope.index = 0; // row index
  $scope.data = []; // array of items
  $scope.keypress = function(offset) {
    console.log('keypress', offset);
    var i = $scope.index + offset;
    if (i < 0) { i = $scope.data.length - 1; }
    if (i >= $scope.data.length) { i = 0; }
  };
  $element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
    console.log('keypress', event, event.which);
    if(event.which === 38) { // up
      $scope.keypress(-1);
    } else if (event.which === 40) { // down
      $scope.keypress(1);
    } else {
      return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}]);


<table class="table table-striped" ng-controller="tableCtrl">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in data[0]">{{key}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data track by $index" ng-click="draw($index)" ng-class="$index == index ? 'info' : ''">
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in row">{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Trying

```
ng-keypress="console.log($event)"
ng-keypress="alert(123)"
```

did nothing for me.

Strangley the sample at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress, which does ng-keypress="count = count + 1", works.

I found an alternate solution, which has pressing Enter invoke the button's ng-click.

```
<input ng-model="..." onkeypress="if (event.which==13) document.getElementById('button').click()"/>
<button id="button" ng-click="doSomething()">Done</button>
```

Comment: `ng-keypress="console.log('foo')"` did not work for me either, but if you do `ng-keypress="fooMethod()"` and in your controller `$scope.fooMethod = function()
    {
        console.log('fooMethod called');
    }` does work.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Informe your name:<input type="text" ng-model="pergunta" ng-keypress="pressionou_enter($event)" ></input> 
<button ng-click="chamar()">submit</button>
<h1>{{resposta}}</h1> 
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
//create a service mitsuplik
app.service('mitsuplik', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (parametro) {
        var tmp = ""; 
        for (var x=0;x<parametro.length;x++)
            {
            tmp = parametro.substring(x,x+1) + tmp;
            } 
        return tmp;
    }
});
//Calling our service
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, mitsuplik) { 
  $scope.chamar = function() { 
        $scope.resposta = mitsuplik.myFunc($scope.pergunta); 
    };
  //if mitsuplik press [ENTER], execute too
  $scope.pressionou_enter = function(keyEvent) {
             if (keyEvent.which === 13) 
                { 
                $scope.chamar();
                }

    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension on the answer from EpokK.

I had the same problem of having to call a scope function when enter is pushed on an input field. However I also wanted to pass the **value of the input field** to the function specified. This is my solution:

```
app.directive('ltaEnter', function () {
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
        if(event.which === 13) {
          // Create closure with proper command
          var fn = function(command) {
            var cmd = command;
            return function() {
              scope.$eval(cmd);
            };
          }(attrs.ltaEnter.replace('()', '("'+ event.target.value +'")' ));

          // Apply function
          scope.$apply(fn);

          event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
};
```

});

The use in HTML is as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="itemname" lta-enter="add()" placeholder="Add item"/>
```

Kudos to EpokK for his answer.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="itemname" ng-model="item.itemname" lta-enter="add(item.itemname)" placeholder="Add item"/>`

Answer (score 1):

What about this?:

```
<form ng-submit="chat.sendMessage()">
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```

Now when you push enter key after write something in your input, the form know how to handle it.

Comment: How/where is ``chat.sendMessage()`` defined

Answer (score 0):

Some example of code that I did for my project.
Basically you add tags to your entity.
Imagine you have input text, on entering Tag name you get drop-down menu with preloaded tags to choose from, you navigate with arrows and select with Enter:

HTML +  AngularJS v1.2.0-rc.3

```
    <div>
        <form ng-submit="addTag(newTag)">
            <input id="newTag" ng-model="newTag" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter new tag"
                   style="padding-left: 10px; width: 700px; height: 33px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 3px;" autofocus
                   data-toggle="dropdown"
                   ng-change="preloadTags()"
                   ng-keydown="navigateTags($event)">
            <div ng-show="preloadedTags.length > 0">
                <nav class="dropdown">
                    <div class="dropdown-menu preloadedTagPanel">
                        <div ng-repeat="preloadedTag in preloadedTags"
                             class="preloadedTagItemPanel"
                             ng-class="preloadedTag.activeTag ? 'preloadedTagItemPanelActive' : '' "
                             ng-click="selectTag(preloadedTag)"
                             tabindex="{{ $index }}">
                            <a class="preloadedTagItem"
                               ng-class="preloadedTag.activeTag ? 'preloadedTagItemActive' : '' "
                               ng-click="selectTag(preloadedTag)">{{ preloadedTag.label }}</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.preloadTags = function () {
    var newTag = $scope.newTag;
    if (newTag && newTag.trim()) {
        newTag = newTag.trim().toLowerCase();

        $http(
            {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'api/tag/gettags',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                mimeType: 'application/json',
                params: {'term': newTag}
            }
        )
            .success(function (result) {
                $scope.preloadedTags = result;
                $scope.preloadedTagsIndex = -1;
            }
        )
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            }
        );
    } else {
        $scope.preloadedTags = {};
        $scope.preloadedTagsIndex = -1;
    }
};

function checkIndex(index) {
    if (index > $scope.preloadedTags.length - 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (index < 0) {
        return $scope.preloadedTags.length - 1;
    }
    return index;
}

function removeAllActiveTags() {
    for (var x = 0; x < $scope.preloadedTags.length; x++) {
        if ($scope.preloadedTags[x].activeTag) {
            $scope.preloadedTags[x].activeTag = false;
        }
    }
}

$scope.navigateTags = function ($event) {
    if (!$scope.newTag || $scope.preloadedTags.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if ($event.keyCode == 40) {  // down
        removeAllActiveTags();
        $scope.preloadedTagsIndex = checkIndex($scope.preloadedTagsIndex + 1);
        $scope.preloadedTags[$scope.preloadedTagsIndex].activeTag = true;
    } else if ($event.keyCode == 38) {  // up
        removeAllActiveTags();
        $scope.preloadedTagsIndex = checkIndex($scope.preloadedTagsIndex - 1);
        $scope.preloadedTags[$scope.preloadedTagsIndex].activeTag = true;
    } else if ($event.keyCode == 13) {  // enter
        removeAllActiveTags();
        $scope.selectTag($scope.preloadedTags[$scope.preloadedTagsIndex]);
    }
};

$scope.selectTag = function (preloadedTag) {
    $scope.addTag(preloadedTag.label);
};
```

CSS + Bootstrap v2.3.2

```
.preloadedTagPanel {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 700px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    padding-top: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.preloadedTagItemPanel {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.preloadedTagItemPanel:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
}

.preloadedTagItemPanelActive {
    background-color: #666666;
}

.preloadedTagItem {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #666666 !important;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.preloadedTagItem:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
}

.preloadedTagItemActive {
    background-color: #666666;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

.dropdown .preloadedTagItemPanel:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a nasty solution. A controller shouldn't handle UI things like keypresses.

Comment: This answer contains a lot of "noise", in a manner of speaking, containing a lot of markup that does — as far as I can see at a glance — not relate to the actual question at hand. It might be more succinct/useful to condense the code in the answer and provide the full example in a gist/jsfiddle/plnkr.

Comment: @MartinAndersen, where should a keypress be handled in an angular app?

Comment: When I look at it now it looks okay. It's basically how keypresses has always been handled with the JS event model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late .. but i found a simpler solution using `auto-focus` .. This could be useful for buttons or other when popping a `dialog` :

`<button auto-focus ng-click="func()">ok</button>`

That should be fine if you want to press the button `on`Space or Enter clicks .

Comment: the question it's about press enter and do something.

Answer (score 0):

here's my directive:

```
mainApp.directive('number', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, el, attr) {
            el.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
                //ignore all characters that are not numbers, except backspace, delete, left arrow and right arrow
                if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 46 && event.keyCode != 37 && event.keyCode != 39) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

usage:

```
<input number />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-keydown , ng-keyup , ng-press such as this .

> to triger a function :

```
   <input type="text" ng-keypress="function()"/>
```

> or if you have one condion such as when he press escape (27 is the key
>   code for escape)

```
 <form ng-keydown=" event.which=== 27?cancelSplit():0">
....
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using document.bind is a bit more elegant

```
constructor($scope, $document) {
  var that = this;
  $document.bind("keydown", function(event) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
      that.handleKeyDown(event);
    });
  });
}
```

To get document to the controller constructor:

```
controller: ['$scope', '$document', MyCtrl]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('dragModule', [])
  .directive('myDraggable', ['$document', function($document) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
         element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
           console.log('keydown keypress', event.which);
            if(event.which === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to get the event is the following:

```
console.log(angular.element(event.which));
```

A directive **can** do it, but that is not **how you** do it.