# Adding Scope to Directive kills model relation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**The Goal:** To provide a series of text fields where when you have it selected and press the enter key it will either add a new text field (if you press enter in the last field) or focus on the next field (if you press enter on any other field).

**The Idea:** Using a directive that detects enter key presses will trigger a callback to the original controller that will be able to perform the necessary tasks.  Ideally this directive will be able to use elsewhere for other actions other than the next / new text fields goal stated above.

**The Problem:** I've written the directive that will detect the enter key press and will then make a call to the callback function WITH the event data (used to detect which field was active when pressing the enter key).  This works great!  *However...* when the `scope: [method: '&ngEnter']` is on the directive it kills all relationship between the text field and the controller *(??)*.  Therefore all textfields are blank (yet the other `sub` data found elsewhere (anywhere but the input) function properly, so the data itself is intact and correct, but when applied to the textfield it acts all screwy.

**The Code:** Found Below...

**Directive: ng_enter.coffee**

```
angular.module('app.common').directive "ngEnter", ['$parse', ($parse) ->
  restrict: 'A'
  scope:
    method: '&ngEnter'
  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    expressionHandler = scope.method()
    element.bind "keydown keypress", (event) ->
      if event.which is 13
        event.preventDefault()
        scope.$apply ->
          expressionHandler(event)
]
```

**my_view.haml**

```
.item-list.sub-item-list.bordered-background
  .item-row(ng-repeat='sub in categoryEditor.categorizations' ng-hide='sub._destroy')
    %div
      %input.left{type: 'text', "ng-model"=>"sub.name", style: 'width: 85%; margin: 0 0 0 1px;', 'ng-enter' => 'subitemEnter'}
      %i.icon-large.right.icon-remove{"ng-click"=>"removeSubItem(sub)", title: "{{sub.name}}"}
```

**my_controller.coffee**

```
angular.module('app.admin.controllers').controller 'MyControllerCtrl', ['$scope', ($scope) ->
  $scope.categoryEditor = {...}
  $scope.subitemEnter = (event) ->
    console.log "subitemEnter() Triggered"
    console.log event
```

**Update**: It appears that `scope` is being overwritten, and i must find a way to solve this without explicitly declaring scope in my directive.

Comment: Why don't you look at ngKeypress http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngKeypress

Comment: Creating a scope object in directive creates an isolated scope, which does not work well with ng-model.

Comment: @Chandermani: I didnt use ngKeyPress becuase I Originally Followed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470790/how-to-use-a-keypress-event-in-angularjs

Comment: @Chandermani It also appears that I do not have access to `ng-keypress` in my current version of angular.  But looking into that lead me to Angular UI Utils that provided a simple / easy solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Angular UI Utils, I was able to get access to `ui-keypress` that provides a easy way of performing callbacks on various keypress events.  The following code is the solution.

**View (.haml):**

```
%input{type: 'text', "ng-model"=>"sub.name", 'ui-keypress' => "{13:'subItemEnterPress($event)'}"}
```

**Controller (.coffee):**

```
  $scope.subItemEnterPress = (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    inputs = $(event.target).closest('.item-list').find('input')
    if event.target == _.last(inputs)
      $scope.addSubItem()
    else
      $(inputs[ _.indexOf(inputs, event.target) + 1 ]).focus()
```