# Alternative way to bind directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know that you can bind a directive by:

Html:

```
<mydirective />
```

Js:

```
app.directive('mydirective', function () {})
```

However I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17472118/1447885) SO answer. **So is it possible to bind a directive like?**

Html:

```
<input ng-something="foo()">
```

Js:

```
app.directive('ngSomething', function () {})
```

Or I should always have `template:` inside the directive so as I inject the code. My purpose is to bind a `ng-keydown` on an existing input:

This does not work :

```
<input type="text", placeholder="Search stuff" ng-model="searchBar" ng-keydown="dosomthg()">
```

So I'm trying based on the above answer:

```
<input type="text", placeholder="Search stuff" ng-model="searchBar" ngSearchbar="dosomthg()">
```

---

Comment: [look here](http://plnkr.co/edit/B2D0PFiPKmxnFzFBBCrZ)... it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should [I] always have template?

No. Apart from modifying DOM structure, directives can provide pure behavior as well.

> So is it possible to bind a directive like: my-directive="someFunction()"

Yes. In the simplest scenario it goes like this [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/tFdXD6AYCZ3WaZdaPGJ6). To your directive you can pass delegates to functions from parent scope and even anonymous angular expression. Take a look and play a bit with it! If you want to know more about it try to read angular [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler).

Comment: Thank you. I also gave `my-directive="someFunction($event)"` to pass the event resources. I was reading the docs but Ajs are not the best :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't always have to include a template. But if you were to include a template, you can do it this way:

**directive**:

```
app.directive('ngSomething', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', // means element
    template: '<input type="text", placeholder="Search stuff" ng-model="searchBar" ng-keydown="dosomthg()">'
  }
});
```

**html**:

```
<ng-something></ng-something>
```

**dosomthg()**:

```
  $scope.dosomthg = function() {
    $scope.name = 'mate';
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/nV57jx?p=preview

Comment: without the directive it works as well... [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/B2D0PFiPKmxnFzFBBCrZ)