# JQuery : Keypress not working on first press

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code

```
  $(currentClass).keypress(function (e) {

            if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                return false;
            }

  });
```

The only problem with this is that, every time I hit a key for the first time regardless a letter or a number, it shows up in my content editable span tag. However, the second time I hit a letter key the code works, it only accepts number. I have no idea what is wrong with this code in the first pressing of keys.

Comment: This is old but wanted to throw this out there,  I was running into issues using .keypress and had to switch to something like the solutions below that use the .on syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I used

```
 if ($.inArray($event.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        ($event.keyCode == 65 && $event.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        ($event.keyCode >= 35 && $event.keyCode <= 39)) {
        // let it happen, don't do anything
        return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if (($event.shiftKey || ($event.keyCode < 48 || $event.keyCode > 57)) && ($event.keyCode < 96 || $event.keyCode > 105)) {
        $event.preventDefault();
    }
```

I was able to solve the problem with this. If their suggestion is not working try this.

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery's `.on()` method.

```
$(currentClass).on("keypress",function (e) {

        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

### Bind Properly your events

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(body).on("keypress","currentClass",function (e) {
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            return false;
        }

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(currentClass).on('keypress', function (e) {
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
               e.preventDefault();
               alert("pressed");
               return false;
    }
});
```

[event - on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

This might helps you :)

Comment: Hi, it works when I try it on another project, however still its the same as my code when I use it in the project mixed with Angular  and Jquery.

Comment: Example for angular.js : http://plnkr.co/edit/OHWDZo68siDlcrXnLyzJ?p=preview 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470790/how-to-use-a-keypress-event-in-angularjs

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find another solution. This one works, but not with the application that I am doing.

Comment: @PipeMan if you got the answer please share it. :) Thanks!!

Comment: Hi! I already posted an answer, please browse the thread. Thanks again!