# Unexpected end of expression ng-keypress event in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `ng-keypress` directive to check `ENTER` key pressed or not.

```
...
...
<input type="text" ng-model="mymodal"
    ng-keypress="($event.charCode==13)?myFunction():return"/>

...
...
```

But when I open page in chrome, it gives error

```
Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: ($event
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.4/$parse/ueoe?p0=(%24event
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12)
    at Parser.consume (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11935:13)
    at Parser.primary (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11866:12)
    at Parser.unary (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12158:19)
    at Parser.multiplicative (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12141:21)
    at Parser.additive (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12132:21)
    at Parser.relational (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12123:21)
    at Parser.equality (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12114:21)
    at Parser.logicalAND (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12105:21)
    at Parser.logicalOR (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12096:21) 
<input type="text" ng-model="mymodal" ng-keypress="($event.charCode==13)?myFunction():return" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
```

If I remove `ng-keypress` or put `""`(Empty string) in expression, its working fine.

Comment: return should have some value true or false

Comment: working here http://plnkr.co/edit/QYWtEwoYKwDO1y1Z6iPQ?p=preview

Comment: @K.Toress, you might be used latest version of angularjs, I am using `1.3.4`

Comment: @ShubhamNigam, I get reference from http://stackoverflow.com/a/30539241/243031

Comment: @K.Toress, it might be related to this https://github.com/angular/angular-hint/issues/98?

Comment: angula version is 1.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to trigger your function on the proviso that the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key was pressed, simply use the following

```
ng-keypress="$event.charCode === 13 && myFunction()"
```

<kbd>[Plunker - Angular@1.3.4](http://plnkr.co/edit/AN3ib8a3frsgWNo2S39K?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: it works, but I have to call method and also assign variable in `ng-keypress` event its like this `ng-keypress="myfunction($event, text); ($event.which === 13)?text='':0"` how to convert it in your syntaxt?

Comment: Can I call function and check condition in same expression ?