# Ng-submit with textarea

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with only a text area. Is it possible to execute `ng-submit` when a user hits enter in the textarea? I'm able to accomplish this using `ng-keyup` but was wondering if there was a better solution.

```
<form ng-show="messages.conversation" ng-submit="messages.reply()">
  <textarea class="msg-textarea" ng-model="messages.replyText" 
            ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? messages.reply() : null">
  </textarea>
  <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" 
          ng-click="messages.reply()">Reply
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EpokK once solved the problem with the following code:
[How to use a keypress event in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470790/how-to-use-a-keypress-event-in-angularjs/17472118#17472118)

You need to add a `directive`, like this:

**Javascript**:

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-enter="doSomething()">    
</div>
```