# Invoke query filter on Enter using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm relatively new to AngularJS, and I'm attempting to build a simple Whiskey search application. Angular makes it easy to bind an input element and my results, but the results filter as the user is typing. I don't want the filter to happen until the user hits Enter.

Here is my code for the input search:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="start typing and hit enter" ng-model="query">
```

And here is my results:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" ng-controller="WhiskeyListCtrl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="whiskey in whiskeys | filter:query">
                <div class="whiskey-container"> 
                    <a href="#/whiskeys/{{whiskey.id}}"><img ng-src="{{whiskey.images[0]}}" height="200" width="200"/></a>
                    <whiskey-title></whiskey-title>
                    <whiskey-desc></whiskey-desc>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***ngModelOptions***

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="start typing and hit enter" ng-model="query" ng-model-options="{updateOn : 'change blur'}">
```

Comment: Welcome, but you cannot say thanks here you have to click the tick mark on my answer to accept it.

Comment: I know, I was just waiting because it didn't let me accept the answer so soon. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help to you?  [How to use a keypress event in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470790/how-to-use-a-keypress-event-in-angularjs)

Look at this by user name [Rodolfo Jorge Nemer Noguieria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1102037/rodolfo-jorge-nemer-nogueira):

Another simple alternative:

```
<input ng-model="edItem" type="text" 
    ng-keypress="($event.which === 13)?foo(edItem):0"/>
```

And the ng-ui alternative:

```
<input ng-model="edItem" type="text" ui-keypress="{'enter':'foo(edItem)'}"/>
```