# Binding keyup in angular 1.6 controller

Tags: angularjs

I use to bind keyup on all input elements in jQuery like this:

```
$("input[type='text']").keyup(doSomething);
```

How can I do this from inside angular controller?
I do not want to write ng-keyup on every input element.

Comment: This seems not be like an Angular 2/4 that you are asking. If so will you please update the tag with `angularjs` instead of `angular`. As [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/info) is for Angular2/4 while `angularjs` is for Angular 1.x.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind function on key up in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052939/bind-function-on-key-up-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: This question was original with Angular 2 tag, So the Answer has Angular 2 reference. I'll delete this answer, since this is no longer valid.

Don't use jQuery in Angular 2 applications. Although you can use that but it is highly discouraged. There is an Angular way to bind the events.
i.e. in view:

```
<button (keyup)="foo($event)">
```

in component:

```
foo(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
}
```

Source: [Angular Cheat Sheet](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet)