# directive not firing on <Enter> keypress

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I was following [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470790/how-to-use-a-keypress-event-in-angularjs) on creating an Enter keypress directive.

Here is my JS, in which I simulate the same functionality:

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
app.directive('myEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
               scope.$apply(function (){
                scope.$eval(attrs.myEnter);
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        }
     });
  };
```

});

```
function callServerWithSong(){
 alert("calling!");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="search" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <input type="text" id="search" my-enter="calServerWithSong()">
</div>
```

The problem is that when I select the input box, type a string and press enter, it doesn't report an error or execute the `alert()` which tells me that my directive must not be properly set up to fire when I keypress that element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a typo of method name while passing through a directive attribute. Also the method should be there in `$scope` of controller.

**HTML**

```
<div id="search" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <input type="text" id="search" my-enter="callServerWithSong()">
</div>
```

**Code**

```
function callServerWithSong(){
 alert("calling!");
}

$scope.callServerWithSong = callServerWithSong;
```