# Individual submit for multiple buttons in one form in angular javascript

Tags: angularjs, forms, triggers, onclick

I have one form which contains three input fields with their own Find button which fetches the different data based on the input. As of now all the buttons have **input type="button"** and they work on the click.

Users expect that on pressing enter button on keyboard, respective find should be called. That means if they have entered some text in field 1, it should trigger find of button1. not sure how to handle this using angularjs

Any thoughts on this will really help me.

Comment: What about adding `ng-enter="testfunction()"` for each text input?

Comment: @Will.Harris Thanks for the answer but I am not sure if its a standard angular directive.

Comment: Apologies. If you are interested in creating your own directive check out the answer to this post then :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470790/how-to-use-a-keypress-event-in-angularjs

Comment: Theres also an example of a similar directive in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lsconyer/bktpzgre/1/

Comment: @Will.Harris the link you provided http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470790/how-to-use-a-keypress-event-in-angularjs led me to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use, `ng-keypress` directive of angular and call a function like this,
`ng-keypress = "submitForm($event)"` in your html,

In your controller, check for the `ENTER KEY` using the event argument passed with the function, i.e

```
$scope.submitForm = function(e) {
 if(e.keyCode == 13) { // for enter key
   // do what ever you want
 }  
}
```

Note: you can also write your own directive for `ENTER KEY`

EDIT: In order to differentiate each keypress, pass another key as a argument with that function and call the appropriate service.