# Send scope data to custom event AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need an event that executes when the user press enter on the element and there is an [answer to that question already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17472118/1874460). But the situation here is that the only thing that I can pass to the callback is the `$event` object but I want to pass the `$scope` data to the callback just like ng-click does:

```
<input type="text" ng-enter="application.search(application.$hass)"/>
```

And in the controller I would have:

```
$scope.application = {
   $hass: "444331"
}

$scope.application.search = function($hass)
{
     alert($hass)// prints 444331
}
```

How can I achieve it.

Comment: make it as value and inject it to the controller angular.value('hass',444331);

Comment: @KarthickKumar do you have any link of an example that i can see?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers please check this link

Comment: @KarthickKumar thank! But remember that the $scope.application.$hass, it can change if i click over another bottom. In the example you gave me, is constant. Sorry i didnt mention that.

Comment: unless you copied that directive incorrectly, this actually works;  there is no reason that you would be limited to `$event`.

Comment: that being said, the directive from that answer was written in 2013 for a different version of angular, and has issues with newer releases of angular, in particular, it throws `$apply` already in progress.

Comment: the value does come through though, so it doesn't even appear like you tested this before asking why it wouldn't work, since I copied literally your code and the directive from the other answer to a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/VSWx30xxeCCi9Qr2njm6?p=preview

Comment: also, don't prefix your directives with `ng`, that is a flag that it is a directive written into the core angular framework; when you ask about your own custom directives but use `ng`, you only confuse people, especially since there is an angular class `.ng-enter`

Comment: @Claies the truth is that i didnot test it, I guess that it was because i assume that it will not work. I tested now and it did worked. I have to thank you for correcting me. I'll try harder the next time. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I still don't think that directive is appropriate for use in current angular versions, but that's a topic for another question.

Comment: I believe that the `this` object is the current `$scope` object, so `search(this, $hass)` should pass the appropriate scope object to the function.