# How to trigger enter key on click a button after writing some text on text box in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a text box and button,onclick of the button I am calling a function after writing some text in text box.I need to call same function on press enter key also.Here is the code below.

### html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="text">
<button ng-click="myFunct()" type="button">click</button> 
</div>
```

### script

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$http) {   
$scope.myFunct = function() {
  alert('I am an alert');
    }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a keypress event in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470790/how-to-use-a-keypress-event-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `ng-keyup` to the input:

```
<input type="text" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? myFunct() : null">
```

Comment: Thanks for your,its helpful for me