# For a search box which method of implementation in correct in case "search on ENTER"? using it in form with ng-submit or in n-keypress?

Tags: angularjs

Im in implementing a single search box ,search while "Enter" and need to know which of the following two is efficient ?

```
1.ng-submit="myFunc()"
2.ng-keypress="($event.charCode==13 && searchTxt.length!=0)? myFunc() : ''"
```

model: searchTxt
please suggest which one is efficient?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a keypress event in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470790/how-to-use-a-keypress-event-in-angularjs)

Comment: I already looked into it but my question is "which  one is efficient"???

Comment: you can use filter to search record using ng-submit directives. As per my opinion ng-submit is efficient to search record on enter key.

Comment: thankyou @AkashPatel