# hide layover (layer/popup) with escape key

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have a layover which I'd like to hide when a user presses the escape key. I have tried to use angular-ui for this, but somehow the event does not seem to be triggered:

```
<div ui-keyup="{'esc':'keypressCallback($event)'}"></div>
```

I get no errors either, so I think the whole binding is not working. Would it maybe only work on input elements, and if so, what other AngularJS method could I use to bind a function to the escape key.

Comment: Put it on the body tag

Answer (score -1):

try with the keydown/keyup events - see this question & its answers: [Clear input text field in Angular / AngularUI with ESC key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646954/clear-input-text-field-in-angular-angularui-with-esc-key)

Comment: This isn't an answer the this question. Your suggestion only works for input controls.